# VBA Excel spellchecking for protected workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to run an automatic Spell checking for my Excel workbook.

Previously I used the method explained in this query:

[Spell check an Excel sheet in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12057456/spell-check-an-excel-sheet-in-vba)

Everything seems to be alright, although at the very end I am getting an error:

**Run-time error '1004':**
**CheckSpelling method of Range class failed**

However, my spellchecking looks like is done, since I have no same errors anymore. Unfortunately, it's quite awkward, because I cannot run another VBA code on my workbook since the debugger shows error.

I found the code relevant for Spellchecking of the protected sheet here:

https://www.computergaga.com/blog/spell-check-a-protected-excel-worksheet/

and finally I prepared my own code including them two:

```
 Sub Spellcheck3()
 For Each sh In Worksheets
 Sheets(sh.Name).Cells.Unprotect "excel"
 ActiveSheet.CheckSpelling
 Sheets(sh.Name).Cells.Protect "excel"
 Next
 End Sub
```

Unfortunately, I am getting error:
**Object doesn't support this property or method.**

The debug line is rough:

```
   Sheets(sh.Name).Cells.Unprotect "excel"
```

Maybe should I target some set of cells on each worksheet as per the query below:
[Excel - VBscript for Spellcheck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19897940/excel-vbscript-for-spellcheck)

I would like to have correct spellchecking with the comment at the end, that everything has been finished correctly. I have some cells protected across my workbook, and that's why the debugger appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `ActiveSheet` is not the sheet you unprotect `Sheets(sh.Name)` and `Cells` as no method `.Unprotect` that is why you get the error

> Object doesn't support this property or method.

It should be

```
Sub Spellcheck3()
    For Each sh In Worksheets
        sh.Unprotect "excel"
        sh.CheckSpelling
        sh.Protect "excel"
    Next sh
End Sub
```

Avoid using `ActiveSheet` at any cost (see also [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)).

Also note that `Sheets(sh.Name)` is a bit overkill. You try to get the name `sh.Name` of a sheet `sh` just to then get the sheet with that name `Sheets(sh.Name)` but you already had that sheet in just `sh`.

Comment: Hi Thanks, It would wor, biut now I am getting error
"The Password you supplied is not correct".

My password is "Secret".
I put the 
sh.Unprotect "Secret"
in my code according to my password setting for each sheet (excluding the 1st one).
Const pw As String = "Secret"

How can I exclude unprotected sheets then?

Comment: I know now. It works, although now I have to figure out how to protect again my sheets from 1 to 10th row as it was before. Thank you.

Comment: @MariuszKrukar Cells have a `Locked` propery have a look at [Range.Locked property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.locked). The ranges where this property is set to `True` will be protected after `sh.Protect` but the cells that have `Locked = False` will not be protected by `sh.Protect`.